# C# to copy xml in excel zip file

Tags: c#, xml, excel

I want to copy xml to excel zip file and if necesaary pick it and update all show in xml.
I have wrote following code but it gives error

```
private void toolStripMenuItemMcDonald_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        saveData();
        string ndocPath = String.Empty;
        OpenFileDialog dlgOpenFile = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (dlgOpenFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            lst = null;
            picClose_Click_1(sender, e);
            docPath = dlgOpenFile.FileName;
            ndocPath = docPath;
        }

        if (ndocPath != String.Empty)
        {
            //auditSummaryDisplay = null;
            //auditSummaryDisplay = new auditSummary();
            beefdoc doc = new beefdoc();
            if (doc.checkDocument(docPath) == true)
            {
                doc.copyCustomXml(docPath);
                auditSummaryDisplay = doc.readCustomXml(docPath);

                saveAuditXML();
             //}
             //else
             //{
             //    auditSummaryDisplay = doc.readCustomXml(docPath);
             }

}
```

then in next class

```
public class beefdoc
{
    private const string ContentTypeNamespace = @"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types";

    private const string spreadsheetmlMlNamespace = @"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main";

    private const string DocumentXmlXPath = "/t:Types/t:Override[@ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml\"]";

    private const string BodyXPath = "/w:document/w:body";

    public bool checkDocument(string path)
    {
        bool bln = false;

        try
        {
            using (Package package = Package.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                System.Uri uriPartTarget = new System.Uri("/docProps/beefaudit.xml", System.UriKind.Relative);

                if (!package.PartExists(uriPartTarget))
                {
                    bln = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    bln = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return bln;
    }

    public void copyCustomXml(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(path);
            Stream documentXml = readDocumentxml(zip);
            XmlDocument xmlDoc_document = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc_document.Load(documentXml);
            zip.Close();

            //remove document xml
            string customDocpath;
            customDocpath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            customDocpath = customDocpath + @"\sheet1.xml";
            XmlDocument xmlDoc1 = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc1.Load(customDocpath);
            byte[] xmlBytes = (new UTF8Encoding()).GetBytes(xmlDoc1.OuterXml.ToString());
              using (SpreadsheetDocument packagedoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(path, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                WorkbookPart mainDocumentPart = packagedoc.AddWorkbookPart();

            //    //mainDocumentPart.Document = new Document();
            //    //Document document = mainDocumentPart.Document;
            //    //Body body = document.AppendChild(new Body());
            //    //body.RemoveAllChildren();
                mainDocumentPart.GetStream().Write(xmlBytes, 0, xmlBytes.Length);


            }



            string customXmlpath;
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            //save document.xml,AuditSummary.xml as custom xml
            using (Package package = Package.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                System.Uri uriPartTarget = new System.Uri("/docProps/beefaudit.xml", System.UriKind.Relative);
                customXmlpath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                customXmlpath = customXmlpath + @"\beefaudit.xml";
                xmlDoc.Load(customXmlpath);

                PackagePart customXml = package.CreatePart(uriPartTarget, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.styles+xml");

                //copy xml inside .docx file
                using (Stream partStream = customXml.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    xmlDoc.Save(partStream);
                }

                System.Uri uriPartTargetdocxml = new System.Uri("/docProps/beefaudit.xml", System.UriKind.Relative);
                if (!package.PartExists(uriPartTargetdocxml))
                {
                    PackagePart customXmldoc = package.CreatePart(uriPartTargetdocxml, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.styles+xml");

                    //copy document.xml inside .docx file
                    using (Stream partStream = customXmldoc.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        xmlDoc_document.Save(partStream);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    package.DeletePart(uriPartTargetdocxml);
                    PackagePart customXmldoc = package.CreatePart(uriPartTargetdocxml, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.styles+xml");

                    //copy document.xml inside .docx file
                    using (Stream partStream = customXmldoc.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        xmlDoc_document.Save(partStream);
                    }
                }
            }
            //return frtDetails;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private Stream readDocumentxml(ZipFile zip)
    {
        string location = "";

        Stream documentXml = null;
        try
        {
            foreach (ZipEntry entry in zip)
            {
                // Find "[Content_Types].xml" zip entry

                if (string.Compare(entry.Name, "[Content_Types].xml", true) == 0)
                {
                    Stream contentTypes = zip.GetInputStream(entry);

                    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
                    xmlDoc.Load(contentTypes);
                    contentTypes.Close();

                    //Create an XmlNamespaceManager for resolving namespaces

                    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr =
                        new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
                    nsmgr.AddNamespace("t", ContentTypeNamespace);

                    // Find location of "document.xml"

                    XmlNode node = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(DocumentXmlXPath, nsmgr);

                    if (node != null)
                    {
                        location = ((XmlElement)node).GetAttribute("PartName");
                        location = location.TrimStart(new char[] { '/' });
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
                throw new System.Exception("It is not a valid Docx file.");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
            {
                foreach (ZipEntry entry in zip)
                {
                    // Find "document.xml" zip entry

                    if (string.Compare(entry.Name, location, true) == 0)
                    {
                        documentXml = zip.GetInputStream(entry);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return documentXml;
    }

    private Stream readCustomxml(ZipFile zip)
    {
        Stream documentXml = null;
        try
        {
            foreach (ZipEntry entry in zip)
            {
                // Find "customxml" zip entry

                if (string.Compare(entry.Name, "/docProps/beefaudit.xml", true) == 0)
                {
                    documentXml = zip.GetInputStream(entry);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (documentXml == null)
                throw new System.Exception("It is not a valid Docx file.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return documentXml;
    }

    public auditSummary readCustomXml(string path)
    {
        auditSummary response = null;
        Stream partStream = null;
        XmlDocument xmlDoc_document = new XmlDocument();
        string xmlText = "";

        string xmlDocument = "";
        try
        {
            using (Package package = Package.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                System.Uri uriPartTargetdocxml = new System.Uri("/docProps/beefaudit.xml", UriKind.Relative);



                PackagePart customXmldoc = package.GetPart(uriPartTargetdocxml);

                //read customxml inside .docx file
                partStream = customXmldoc.GetStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(partStream);
                xmlText = reader.ReadToEnd();


            }

            //response = DeserializeXmlToObject(xmlText);

            //FrontPage ftPage = new FrontPage();
            //ftPage.readFrontPage(
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return response;
    }
```

private beefauditsummary DeserializeXmlToObject(string xml)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(StringToByteArrayUtf8(xml)))
            {
                XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(beefauditsummary));

```
            using (StreamReader xmlStreamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                return (beefauditsummary)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlStreamReader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it gives error wwhile deserialisation the xml like xml error(2,2)

and my xml is ok
xml given as

```
 <tags>
    <tag>
      <tagText>Livestock Receiving</tagText>
      <tagId>1</tagId>
      <subtag>
        <id>1.1</id>
        <text>Transporter expectations</text>
        <displayText>Transporter expectations</displayText>
      </subtag>
    </tag>
 </tags>
 <topicsType>
    <topics>
      <tagId>1</tagId>
      <header>Viewing 0 Questions -&gt; Level : Livestock Receiving</header>
      <Questions />
    </topics>
    <topics>
      <tagId>1.1</tagId>
      <header>Viewing 1 Questions -&gt; Level : Transporter expectations</header>
      <Questions>
        <question qid="1.1" id="1">
          <questionText>Must have written expectations and humane guidelines for transporters.</questionText>

          <answer  anstext="" />
          <description></description>


        </question>
       </Questions>
    </topics>
</topicsType>
  </Root>
```

Comment: which line is giving error?

Comment: >if (string.Compare(entry.Name, "/docProps/beefaudit.xml", true) == >0)
              >  {
                   > documentXml = zip.GetInputStream(entry);
                    break;
                }

Comment: i have no idea what is path for it.I know for word file

Comment: What is the exact error, and the SINGLE line that is giving the error?

Comment: You can't just say "it gives error" with no information and expect us to tell you what's wrong.  It tells you what the error is and which exact line it's happening on, so there's no reason you can't include that information in your question. If you want help here, provide as much detail as you have so we can help. (And when you add details, [edit] your question and add them there instead of in the comments, so that people can easily see them and so you can properly format them so they're readable.)